# How to use just one legend in one plot of three curves?

Tags: matlab, plot, legend, figure

How can I use just one legend that says "hopf" for the dotted line and "ACDC" for the continuous line?

The code I am using is this:

```
clear; close 
Tspannew=linspace(1,100,1000);
ys_new=[]
ysp= []
for i = 1:3
ysp= i^2.*sin(Tspannew)
ys_new(:,i)=ysp

ACDCp=i^2*cos(Tspannew)
yn_ACDC(:,i)= ACDCp
end    

close;
figure
plot(Tspannew,ys_new,'--','DisplayName','Hopf Fold'); 
hold on;
plot(Tspannew,yn_ACDC,'DisplayName','ACDC')
hold off
legend
```

But, it generates 6 legends. I just need two legends related with the continuous line and the dotted line.

Comment: Make sure to first plot ONE dashed line, then ONE continuous line, then the rest. Then call `legend()` with just two arguments, i.e. `legend('Dashed', 'continuous')`. It will ignore the other lines in that case.

Comment: I can only imagine to do it with a for-loop and using `plot(...,'HandleVisibility','off')` for all the index beside the first one

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I tested the following code with Octave 5.1.0, but I got the idea directly from MATLAB's [`legend`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html) documentation: See the [`subset`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html#bt6ef_q-1-subset) version there. You can collect the graphic objects of your plots and select one or more specific lines from both "line collections".

Let's see this code:

```matlab
Tspannew = linspace(1, 100, 1000);
ys_new = [];
ysp = [];
for ii = 1:3
  ysp = ii^2.*sin(Tspannew);
  ys_new(:, ii) = ysp;
  ACDCp = ii^2*cos(Tspannew);
  yn_ACDC(:, ii) = ACDCp;
end    

figure(1);
hold on;
hopf = plot(Tspannew, ys_new, '--', 'DisplayName', 'Hopf Fold');
acdc = plot(Tspannew, yn_ACDC, 'DisplayName', 'ACDC');
hold off;
legend([hopf(1); acdc(1)], ['HOPF legend text'; 'ACDC legend text']);
```

I get the following output, which corresponds to each the first line from the "line collections":

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

Comment: You could also set the `HandleVisibility` property to be `off`, e.g. `set(hopf(2:end),'HandleVisibility','off')`

Comment: @user12339314 When I add this, the `ylim` property is (also) manipulated. The plot is limited to `[-1.0 ... 1.0]`, as this is the value range of `acdc(1)` and `hopf(1)`. So, next to these two additional commands, you would (also) need to correct the `ylim`. Not sure, if that's the best way. But, yes, the resulting legend is the same.

Comment: that sounds like an Octave bug, I don't see that in Matlab (R2017a)

Comment: @user12339314 Ha! And again, one of the many differences... Good to know, that your idea works in MATLAB then!